# Know the exact path of error

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am working on a site built with Code Igniter. It is showing a script error in the console but not the path.

I am having more than 100 files which consists of small or big scripts. Now how I am able to know from which file the error is coming from?

Anyone aware from any tool or any easy method I can try with my site?

Here is [my site](http://www.edushikshaguide.com/) for reference.

Comment: open page view source and check error line  number 346

Comment: Chrome console shows that the error is located at `(index):346`, so all you have to do is view the source of the current HTML document, and check around that line number ...

Comment: Thanks. I have gone through the process you both mentioned above and found the issue. Cheers..

Answer (score 3):

There is error in your **ajax** , function name as **login** , In your success response there is missing closing bracket.

Replace code as following :

```
    function login(){
    //alert("hhh");

        var name = $('#name').val();
       // alert(name);
        var password = $('#logpassword').val();
        //alert(password);
        if(name.trim() == '' ){
           $('#errorname').html('<span style="color:red;">Please Enter Your Name.</p>');
            $('#inputName').focus();
            return false;
        }else if(password.trim() == '' ){
            $('#errorpassword').html('<span style="color:red;">Please Enter Your Password.</p>');
            $('#password').focus();
            return false;
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'http://www.edushikshaguide.com/frontend/system_login',
                data:{name:name,password:password},
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
                },
                success:function(data){
console.log('success');
                }   
            });
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks got it and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In any decent browser you just need to click:

[image: Firefox Developer Tools]

Error here is in line 346, column 9, highlighted for your convenience:

[image: Offending line]

In any case, browser-based JavaScript is a client-side language. Neither PHP nor CodeIgniter have anything to do with it unless you use either to generate JavaScript code dynamically.